# Regarding the argument of d-dimensional copula function in R

Tags: r, command-line-arguments

I have a simple question on R. This is a simple code to generate random variables from a bivariate normal clayton copula with normally distributed margins. How could I do this neatly if I had d equally distributed margins, without having to write c("norm","norm","norm", ... ) etc.?

```
 myMvd1 <- mvdc(copula = archmCopula(family = "clayton", param = 2),
                margins = c("norm", "norm"), paramMargins = list(list(mean = 0,
                sd = 1), list(mean = 0, sd = 1)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rep`:

```
 d <- 5
 mvdc(copula = archmCopula(family = "clayton", param = 2),
      margins = rep("norm", d),
      paramMargins = rep(list(list(mean = 0, sd = 1)), d))
```

(And not knowing what this is about, I am not sure if `param` should be `2` or `d`.)

Comment: Looks like 'dim'-argument to archmCopula should be 'd'. "param" is an argument to the "generator function".

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
matrix(rMvdc(d*nRow, myMvd1),nRow,d)
```